# i can not opent my pbix file in another system

Tags: powerbi

I made a query with version 2021 and when I want to open it on another system, it installs there 2020 and does not allow me to open my pbix file, and I also do not have permission to update PowerBI. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Please download the latest version on the second system and then try opening the pbix. This might work.
You can download it from here.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494

Comment: i need run my pbix file in server system in my company and i can't update  version i make this pbix file in another server system  of my company

Comment: If you have to run it on your "server system", you will have to update Power BI desktop. If the requirement if to publish the pbix to Power BI service, you can directly publish it using Power BI service on your server system.

Comment: Why do you have to open it? What's your end goal?

Comment: If I had permission to update PowerBI, my problem would be solved with 3 clicks

Comment: I prepared the file on another company server that is connected to SQL Server. Now I want to implement it on another server which is also connected to the same SQL Server but with a different name, but the problem is that the new server is a version of PowerB. It is 2020 and I can not run my file in it

Comment: Your best alternative, in this case, would be to find a third machine that can connect to this SQL Server and you have permission to download the Power BI desktop. 

If you cannot arrange for a third machine and your has to go to Power BI Service at the end, you can update your report on your first machine to include server name and database as parameters. Then publish the report on your second machine using the Power BI service (browser) and then update your parameters on the service. Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is not having a third system connected to SQL. The problem is that the managers of the organization want this report that I created on PowerBI version 2021 on PowerBI version 2020

Comment: Do they use Power BI Desktop? Does your company not have a Power BI license?

Comment: yes i use Power BI Desktop and It has a license to use, but I do not know the reason for their insistence on using Power BI 2020

Comment: If you have a Power BI license, then please use the parameter approach. Power BI 2020 is not a valid situation. You may want to get in touch with your company to get more clarity on why they want to use Power BI Desktop 2020 version.

Comment: They only want the file in PowerBI version may 2020. ok thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, we are out of options here then. Please advise them to upgrade to the latest Power BI desktop. You may also want to wait for suggestions from other people.